# model name don't want to override if a same model name using in different fields

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding

I have model and I am binding for two sides. First side is inside of the html p tag.
second side is textarea.
when i change the textarea, inside of the p changes too. 
How can i change only textarea?

```
<div class="title-content">
  <p>{{currentNew.Title}}</p>
</div>
<textarea class="title-textarea" ng-model="currentNew.Title" maxlength="70" style="display:none"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the one way binding `::` in the paragraph

```
<div class="title-content">
  <p>{{::currentNew.Title}}</p>
</div>
<textarea class="title-textarea" ng-model="currentNew.Title" maxlength="70" style="display:none"></textarea>
```

Comment: then I should delete my answer :O

Comment: @Serkan Soydam nice make sure to check this as answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you are binding the same scope with `textarea` and `p` tag. In angular if we are defining any scope variable and if any change occurs in that scope variable ,it reflects everywhere on the page.

> So either you have to use another variable name or you have to use one way data binding of angularJs